# Relay continuous current ratings vs size

Tags: current, relay

I am designing a relay board for my motorcycle to control power to various accessories - lights, heated gear, horn, GPS, etc. It's a pretty straightforward design, some terminals, fuses, and relays.

Nothing really new except the goal is to make it small because my bike doesn't have much space and it's a good excuse to practice PCB layout.

Right now I have a few channels and relays that can be individually controlled by various switches. I figured the maximum current any channel will realistically see is 10-12 A so I went on Digikey and searched for 12 VDC automotive relays rated for 20 A and higher.

I ordered [this little guy](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G8N-1H-AS-DC12-BY-OMR1/6817243) which is rated at 30 A.

When I got it in the mail I honestly don't believe this is rated for 30 A. It's so tiny. Every other automotive relay I've dealt with is HUGE. I've also used 10 A relays that are 3X this size.

Everything I'm reading says this is fine, and that if the switching current rating is 30 A then the continuous current rating is probably even higher. I still don't believe it though, because it's so small. Even the power pins are small, they look equivalent to 20 or 22awg wire.

I kept looking around and found some other relays (similar form factor) that specifically say in the datasheet they're made for lights and heaters. The one linked above says it's used for window motors and such (things that get used for maybe 5-10 seconds at a time). But just looking at the numbers, there's nothing that says it can't be used continuously.

Am I missing something here? Would this thing be fine with a 30 A resistive load running through it for 6 hours or would it just melt? Please enlighten me. There doesn't seem to be any link between size and current carrying capacity. And there also doesn't seem to be any reasoning for the datasheet numbers and the "typical applications" either.

Comment: I would trust Omron, they're a very reputable brand and you got it from a reputable seller. In the datasheet they *do* advertise these as the "smallest class in the industry", which makes me think they were deliberately designed to be small. It does specify that its rated load is only 25 amps, but that's a motor load; loads with better power factor may be less stress on the part.

Comment: [The datasheet](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g8n.pdf) says: "Even at a small size, high-wattage switching is possible due to the contacts and heat-release design. 100,000 times at 14VDC/25A". So I guess they used their magic and stand behind it. Altough it clearly says 25A for "rated load" in the datasheet and 30A for "max. switching current".

Comment: Wow. That's small af

Comment: Automotive relays may be the sizes they are due to being standard sizes, with standard size connectors. If you save enough on the size with that relay, perhaps you could use two and spread the loads between them.

Answer (score 1):

Omron is a reliable company. If they say it's rated at 30 switching resistive, it **will** give you the stated 100,000 operations life switching 30A resistive under the stated test conditions.

Take care that the life ratings of relays (in general, and including this one) are with no diode across the coil so adding a diode (rather than something that allows the coil voltage to go much higher) may reduce the relay life.

As far as continuous current rating, the overcurrent failure curves from [this](https://cdn.sos.sk/productdata/aa/64/db2cf4bc/g8n-1-12dc.pdf) datasheet indicate that it might be a bit close at 85°C Ta and 25A continuous.

So maybe you're onto something there. Looks like if the ambient is hot you might want to keep the current a lot lower than 25A to be conservative.

[image]

Comment: I like to use a diode in series with a zener, to prevent huge spikes but still allow for a faster turn-off than you'd get just using a 1N4004.

Comment: @Hearth Or a diode plus a resistor.

Comment: Thank you so much! Where did you find those graphs? I don't see them in the datasheet. Am I correct in interpreting this graph that the current can be applied for an infinite amount of time if kept below ~25A? Is 85C junction temperature, ambient, or coil?

You have me intrigued by the diode comment. I planned to put a 1N4007 freewheeling diode on each relay. Are you saying this is a bad thing?

Comment: @kobra20 Ah, I guess I went looking for a better datasheet when I saw the Digikey one. Link added. Sorry about that.

Comment: The diode slows the opening of the relay and can reduce the lifetime somewhat in terms of switching operations. A lot of designers don't care and use it because it saves a part. You can use a diode + Zener or a diode + resistor to protect the transistor.

Comment: As far as the exact interpretation of the datasheet, I would refer you to the manufacturer, since the optimistic interpretation may not be the correct one (often isn't with datasheets).

Comment: Thanks again! I also went searching and found 3 different datasheets for that same p/n. Thanks for making it confusing, Omron! It says right on top that the max carry current is 25A for 1hr at 20C (ambient?). Really good info and reassuring that I can use this relay in my design.

Comment: @kobra20 What current are you actually going to use it at? And how hot ambient?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Realistically, no more than 12A continuous. My concern was that since it will be on for 1-2 hours at a time, it could overheat. Ambient temps will range from 0 to 50C.

Comment: Might be worth an e-mail to their engineers.

Comment: Will do. With regards to the Zener diode selection - do you have any suggestions (voltage & power)? (I realize this is creeping away from my original topic, so feel free to message me if you see this.)

Comment: You look at the SOA of the transistor (not just the voltage rating!) and use up a fair bit of it. So if you can safely handle 50V for (say) 8ms and the relay is 12V you might use  a 33V or 35V zener + series diode. Or use a 48V zener across the transistor if the 12V supply bypass is close by. Or use a resistor in series with the diode of (say) 33V/Icoil where Icoil is the worst-case coil current (at low temperature and high supply voltage). Or just use the diode if you don't need full life. A 500mW zener is fine.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am not using a transistor to drive these relays, since I'm working with a common voltage and ground it'll be controlled by various switches (brake light +12V, or grounding to chassis). I still think it's a good idea to use a freewheeling diode to protect the ECU and any other sensitive electronics on the bike. How does this information affect the zener selection? (By the way you are awesome and thanks again for the help)

Comment: On a motorbike? Just use the diode as you would have originally.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think I'd still like to use one to extend relay life as much as possible. So a regular diode (1N4007) plus a zener (specs TBD) on the coil will muffle the spikes while letting the relay open quickly as possible. Maybe this one? https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/BZT52C12-7-F/717727